# How can I pass non-serializable object in pyspark rdd map?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new bee to Spark and Python.
Writing a small PySpark job to read data from S3 bucket and publish the data to Kafka in avro.

Below is the part of the code where I am trying to pass pre initialised/configured producer object to spark map so that once it is initialised and used to producer records in map function.

But I am getting 'SerializingProducer' not serializable error (Pickling error).

How can I approach this problem? I dont want to initialize producer for every record, instead initialise once and use that producer object to produce each record from DF/RDD.

```
from confluent_kafka import SerializingProducer


.....
.....
avro_kafka_producer = SerializingProducer(producer_conf)

df = spark.read.csv(bucket_path_for_table, sep="|",header=False, schema=csv_schema)

rdd = csv_records_df.toJSON().map(lambda record:transform.map_record(avro_kafka_producer, record))
total_count = temp_rdd1.count()
```

Comment: You cannot. How should Spark pass a non serializable object from the driver to one of the executors (over the network)? To solve your problem, you could check [mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions.html)

Comment: Thanks  you , will give a try